# User input column name

Tags: r, rename, user-input

I would like to create a variable where the user can input a specific column name so that it can be referenced in the code without changing every instance. For example:

```
x<<- "insert Description Column Name Here"
y<<- "insert Description Column Number Here"
```

So that I can run things later on that refer to that column. For example:

```
newdata<-strsplit(as.character(data$x),split = ' ') 
newdata2<-newdata(order(newdata[,y]))
```

I have not been successful in finding anything on this topic.

Comment: Have you tried something like: colnames(x) <- c("name1", "name2")?

Comment: you mean interactively? `(x <- readline(prompt = 'Enter column name: '))`

Comment: I wont know how many columns are going to be in the loaded data. I only want to use two of them, a description and category. The column names in the data could differ from user to user. So I want the user to be able to define the names in one place so that they do not have to go and find every instance. I have tried renaming features but have had no success.

Comment: #rawr  They will have access to my script and be able to edit it, but I would like them to be able to just type it in once.

Comment: I should have been more clear rawr. I want the user to name x as a column name in there loaded data. So that I can call it (data$x) later, since I wont know the name of their columns.